# Entry rule position convention in BNF?

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, ebnf, formal-languages

Is it mandatory for the first (topmost) rule of an BNF (or EBNF) grammar to represent the entry point? For example, from the [wikipedia BNF page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), the US Postal address grammar below has `<postal-address>` as the first derivation rule, and also the entry point:

```
<postal-address> ::= <name-part> <street-address> <zip-part>

      <name-part> ::= <personal-part> <last-name> <opt-suffix-part> <EOL> 
                    | <personal-part> <name-part>

  <personal-part> ::= <first-name> | <initial> "." 

 <street-address> ::= <house-num> <street-name> <opt-apt-num> <EOL>

       <zip-part> ::= <town-name> "," <state-code> <ZIP-code> <EOL>

<opt-suffix-part> ::= "Sr." | "Jr." | <roman-numeral> | ""
    <opt-apt-num> ::= <apt-num> | ""
```

Am I at liberty to put the `<postal-address>` rule in, say, the second position, and so provide the grammar in the following alternate form:

```
      <name-part> ::= <personal-part> <last-name> <opt-suffix-part> <EOL> 
                    | <personal-part> <name-part>

 <postal-address> ::= <name-part> <street-address> <zip-part>

  <personal-part> ::= <first-name> | <initial> "." 

 <street-address> ::= <house-num> <street-name> <opt-apt-num> <EOL>

       <zip-part> ::= <town-name> "," <state-code> <ZIP-code> <EOL>

<opt-suffix-part> ::= "Sr." | "Jr." | <roman-numeral> | ""
    <opt-apt-num> ::= <apt-num> | ""
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a requirement.   It is just a convention used by some.

In practice, one must designate "the" goal rule.   We have  set of tools in which one identifies the nonterminal which is *the* goal nonterminal, and you can provide the rules (including goal rules) in any order.  How you designate that may be outside the grammar formalism, or may be a special rule included in the grammar.

As a practical matter, this is not a big deal (OK, so some tool insists you put all the goal rules first, not actually that hard) and not that hard to do nicely (ok, the tool checks the left hand side of a grammar rule to see if it matches the goal nonterminal).

Of course, you need to know which way your tool works, but that takes about 2 minutes to figure out.

Some tools only allow *one* goal rule.  As a practical matter, real (re-engineering, see my bio) parsers often find it useful to allow multiple rules (consider parsing COBOL as "whole programs" and as "COPYLIBS"), so you end up writing (clumsily IMHO):

```
 G = G1 | G2 | G3 ... ;
 G1 = ...
```

in this case. Still not a big deal.  None of these constraints hurt expressiveness or in fact cost you much engineering time.

Comment: I agree with you. I also now recall that a context-free grammar is a 4-tuple, one entry of which is the start symbol.

Comment: Done. I'm still curious as to whether, assuming only *one* goal rule is present, whether such a tool can *always* identify it.

Comment: If your grammar is connected, sure.  Its the only nonterminal not used in some other rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And how soon can we give that tool a problem? Already with two goal rules? Can the input string not be used to help resolve which is the relevant goal rule?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last question.  "Give *that* tool..." which tool?   There are lots of grammar processing tools; you can give them all grammars to process now.  "Already with two goal rules?"  I don't know about *other* tools, but I know ours is happy to accept as many goal rules as you want to provide.  "Can the input string...."  what input string? to the grammar analysis tool?  Yes, you can define your tool to detect "the goal" nonterminal as being the only one not used in some other rule.